Disarming Problem UAV with Ardupilot and Ros2
I am coding a script to drive a drone automatically. I use Ardupilot and ROS2. Moreover, I am using Python for ROS2. I have a problem about disarming the drone. When I run the python code, my drone is armed in the beginning but after a couple of seconds it is disarmed. For this reason, my commands cannot be working. What is the solution of this problem. You can see my python code below.
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node
from geographic_msgs.msg import GeoPointStamped
from mavros_msgs.msg import PositionTarget
from mavros_msgs.srv import CommandBool, SetMode

class Arac:

    # arm operation
    # System.sleep(50000000)
    # codes

    def __init__(self,mode):
        self.mode = mode

class FollowMe(Node):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('follow_me_node')

        # Publisher for setting target position
        self.target_pub = self.create_publisher(PositionTarget, '/mavros/setpoint_raw/local', 10)
        
        # Service clients
        self.arming_client = self.create_client(CommandBool, '/mavros/cmd/arming')
        self.mode_client = self.create_client(SetMode, '/mavros/set_mode')

        # Subscriber for target GPS position
        self.create_subscription(GeoPointStamped, '/target_position', self.target_callback, 10)
        
        self.target_position = GeoPointStamped()
        self.timer = self.create_timer(0.1, self.publish_target_position)  # 10 Hz

        # Wait for service availability
        while not self.arming_client.wait_for_service(timeout_sec=1.0):
            self.get_logger().info('Arming service not available, waiting...')
        while not self.mode_client.wait_for_service(timeout_sec=1.0):
            self.get_logger().info('Mode service not available, waiting...')

        # Arm and set to GUIDED mode
        self.arm()
        self.set_guided_mode()

    def arm(self):
        self.get_logger().info("Arming drone")
        arm_req = CommandBool.Request()
        arm_req.value = True
        future = self.arming_client.call_async(arm_req)
        rclpy.spin_until_future_complete(self, future)
        if future.result().success:
            self.get_logger().info('Drone armed successfully!')
        else:
            self.get_logger().error('Failed to arm drone.')

        self.get_logger().info("Setting mode to GUIDED")
        mode_req = SetMode.Request()
        mode_req.custom_mode = 'GUIDED'
        self.mode_client.call_async(mode_req)
    def set_guided_mode(self):
        self.get_logger().info("Setting mode to GUIDED")
        mode_req = SetMode.Request()
        mode_req.custom_mode = 'GUIDED'
        self.mode_client.call_async(mode_req)

    def target_callback(self, msg):
        self.target_position = msg

    def publish_target_position(self):
        target = PositionTarget()
        target.coordinate_frame = PositionTarget.FRAME_LOCAL_NED
        target.type_mask = PositionTarget.IGNORE_VX | PositionTarget.IGNORE_VY | PositionTarget.IGNORE_VZ \
                           | PositionTarget.IGNORE_AFX | PositionTarget.IGNORE_AFY | PositionTarget.IGNORE_AFZ \
                           | PositionTarget.IGNORE_YAW | PositionTarget.IGNORE_YAW_RATE

        # Convert GPS to local coordinates here (this is simplified)
        target.position.x = self.target_position.position.latitude
        target.position.y = self.target_position.position.longitude
        target.position.z = 15.0  # desired altitude

        self.target_pub.publish(target)

def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)
    follow_me = FollowMe()
    try:
        rclpy.spin(follow_me)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    follow_me.destroy_node()
    rclpy.shutdown()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

